# call another task from a task

Tags: coffeescript, cakefile

How can I call another task from a task in Cakefile ?

I tried `tasks[taskName].action options` but didn't work because `tasks` in not bound in the scope of my Cakefile:

```
  /home/omer/___/Cakefile:52
  return console.log(tasks);
                     ^
  ReferenceError: tasks is not defined
  ...
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `invoke` to invoke another task in the same cakefile.

Comment: Yes, it's on coffeescript.org : `ou can use the invoke function:  invoke 'build'`